# React Native for Web: My component does not re-render when state is updated

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I'm new to React and I've been working on React only for the past 2 days. I'm trying to fetch data from an API. But when the data is updated, the state does not get updated and the component is not re-rendered. But a refresh of the page does that job done.

Here's my code for my component:

```
import { View, FlatList, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'

class Products extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            dataSource: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        fetch("http://localhost:8000/index.php")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            this.setState({
                dataSource: responseJson
            })
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }



    renderItem = (data) =>
        <TouchableOpacity>
            <Text>{data.item.product_name}</Text>
            <Text>{data.item.product_description}</Text>
            <Text>{data.item.product_model}</Text></TouchableOpacity>


        return (
            <View>
                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.dataSource}
                    renderItem={item => this.renderItem(item)}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                />
            </View>
        )
}

export default Products
```

Comment: Hi @Srath, could you post some of your responseJson?

Answer (score 0):

As you're using a class component you need to create a render method, the return works only in functions components, try it

```
import { View, FlatList, Text, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native'

class Products extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            dataSource: []
        }
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        fetch("http://localhost:8000/index.php")
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then((responseJson) => {
            this.setState({
                dataSource: responseJson
            })
        })
        .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }



    renderItem = (data) =>
        <TouchableOpacity>
            <Text>{data.item.product_name}</Text>
            <Text>{data.item.product_description}</Text>
            <Text>{data.item.product_model}</Text></TouchableOpacity>

    render() {
            return (<View>
                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.dataSource}
                    renderItem={item => this.renderItem(item)}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                />
            </View>);
    }
}

export default Products
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding extraData prop to FlatList `extraData={this.state.dataSource}` what it does is re render the FlatList whenever the specified data in extraData changes.

Answer (score 0):

you must wrap `return(...)` with `render()` function when you use class-based component.

```
    render() {
        return (
            <View>
                <FlatList
                    data={this.state.dataSource}
                    renderItem={item => this.renderItem(item)}
                    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
```